# Spaces doesn't come after nl2br(htmlentities($text))?

Tags: php

I am printing a article with spaces inside the article.
Text inside article has HTML tags also,so i am using htmlentities before echo.

But problem is that display does't show spaces on the browser.
What is the problem with these commands?

Can someone please suggest me a better option?

DB update command:

```
 mysql_real_escape_string($text, $db)
```

Article display command:

```
echo nl2br(htmlentities($row_page['text']));
```

Example: displayed text is pretty ugly

Real text and i am expecting same:

```
dbus-1/                   libcom_err.so.2@                     libglib-2.0.so.0@            liblvm2cmd.so.2.02*      libpopt.so.0.0.0*
device-mapper/            libcom_err.so.2.1*                   libglib-2.0.so.0.2200.5*     libm-2.12.so*            libproc-3.2.8.so*
firmware/                 libcrypt-2.12.so*                    libgmodule-2.0.so.0@
```

Comment: "Spaces"? Do you mean "newlines"? Also, please show the original text, the actual result and the expected result.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` will do, no need for `htmlentities()`.  Re spaces, can you show an example? You are aware that multiple spaces are displayed as one in HTML?

Comment: The problem you have here on SO is the same as on your site: the browser collapses whitespace.

Comment: why it collapse white space? any rescue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML collapses all whitespace (spaces or newlines or tabs) into a single space. You can work around it by replacing `'  '` with `' &nbsp;'`, for example:

```
echo str_replace('  ', ' &nbsp;', nl2br(htmlentities($row_page['text'])));
```

But even cleaner is to just have the browser use `pre` formatted whitespace:

```
<pre><?php echo htmlentities($row_page['text']); ?></pre>
```

Or alternatively use CSS for a bit of extra flexibility:

```
<div style="white-space: pre;"><?php echo htmlentities($row_page['text']); ?></div>
```

Pre formatted whitespace has some drawbacks, for example you can't have any newlines or indentation in your HTML file when you're using `pre`, because the browser will render them. But when you really need to control how something is rendered it's the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers collapse continuous whitespace into a single space. That's the way it works, mainly so you can write source code like this:

```
<p>
    Some very long text nicely indented and readable in source,
    so it's easy to write for the author.
</p>
```

and it will display nicely in a browser like this:

> Some very long text nicely indented and readable in source, so it's easy to write for the author.

To use pre-formatted text, wrap that section in a `<pre>` tag or use the equivalent CSS rule `white-space: pre`. The way you're escaping HTML makes this rather difficult of course. A markup language like [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) may be the solution there.